# how to disallow default namespace in a chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I need to build a chart, and disallow this chart to be installed in default namespace.

How to prevent my chart to be install in default namespace(namespace is empty)?

for example: (relase name is test-chart)

(1). helm install  test-chart myChart.tgz                          (not allowed)

(2). helm install  test-chart myChart.tgz -n test-namespace        (OK)

Need to add policy in chart template?

or add annotations in pod?

or add policy in cluster level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard Helm top-level object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) includes the namespace name, possibly `default`.  You can compare on this and use the [`fail`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#fail) template function to abort execution.  This check can go anywhere in your template code.  For example:

```yaml
{{/* templates/deployment.yaml */}}
{{- if eq .Release.Namespace "default" }}
{{- fail "cannot deploy into 'default' namespace }}
{{- end }}
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
...
```

There's no specific way to require a `helm -n` option; is one isn't provided then the default namespace from the Kubernetes configuration is used, which may or may not be `default`.  Even if you wouldn't normally allow deploying into `default` in production there may be other environments like developer Minikube clusters where it's okay, and I might hesitate to add this specific check.